# How do I connect my Sixaxis Playstation3 controller to my laptop?

Tags: bluetooth, gamepad

I have a Lenovo X61t laptop and I'd like to use a Sony Sixaxis PlayStation 3 bluetooth controller.

How can I get the controller to talk to my laptop?

Answer (score 2):

It seems a bit complicated to do but here is a guide: http://www.pabr.org/sixlinux/sixlinux.en.html

Comment: Travis, I had this working with software from the repos (albeit via USB).  Hopefully there are guides out there that don't involve hexdumps and c programming!

Comment: Sorry Travis - you might be right.  The bluetooth element is a shocker.  USB works almost out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier way to go:

First install QTSixA:

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:falk-t-j/qtsixa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install qtsixa
```

Then:
Connect your PS3 controller via USB, and then type "sudo sixpair".
After that, unplug the controller. Activate your Bluetooth.
Start typing "sixad --start" in your Terminal
..follow the instructions and Press the PS-Button...
and then Start QTSixA.

Here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2yKiMxisM0 is a very good video tutorial, if you need a better explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a post and rolled a `.deb`  for Precise 12.04:

https://iwilcox.me.uk/2012/sixaxis-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

The [official community documentation is here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sixaxis).

But [this site](http://psubuntu.com/wiki/SetupSixAxis) details a much simpler method using a QT-based GUI program.  I've used this myself in USB mode and it works perfectly.  Note that you'll have to re-pair using this tool everytime you use your Sixaxis with your PS3 again.

Answer (score 0):

I made a script wich can install your Sixaxis easilly ! (its my first, i need some feedbacks at : usfame@sfr.fr (please)) download link : http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?279kz17cmh9cdbu

Comment: I get "Invalid or deleted file" when I try to download that. Anyway, since it's a script, I recommend sharing it somewhere like http://paste.ubuntu.com/ or http://pastebin.com/. You can edit your question to fix the download link.